# What are the benefits of using the scala akka toolkit vs java akka toolkit version?

Tags: java, scala, akka

In my team we are trying to decide what path to take, if Scala (somehow unknown) or Java (very well known).

We are completely bought that our problem would be best solved by an actor type system, hence Akka but we lack Scala proficiency.

What benefits would there be to using the scala library over java library to do this project?

Comment: Are there any real limitation in the java based akka or they are compatible 100%, only using different language?

Comment: @Stephen C, aniumson. I am not sure how can I make it not based on opinions? what if I ask limitations or difference between libraries? I have asked this question many times (other places than stackoverflow) and people seem to find it interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Akka does asynchronous I/O using Java NIO - so one thread can handle many simultaneous requests.  Traditional Java server frameworks use one-thread-per-socket I/O.  So, if you need your code to scale to, say, 10K open connections on a single VM, without needing to spawn 10K threads to do it, then you probably want something asynchronous.

There are Java-language frameworks such as [Netty](http://netty.io) or [Atmosphere](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere) which also do asynchronous I/O - so you don't have to use Scala if your team is already adept at Java.

Comment: actually we are building on top of Atmosphere. Do you think that's over redundant?

Comment: Not necessarily. The challenge with asynchronous stuff is that you really need the entire stack to be asynchronous to get all the benefits - file I/O, database drivers, you name it.  So if it's a choice between using another framework that is or isn't, you're better off with something which is.

Comment: Thanks @Tim Boudreau, I think I wasn't clear when asking, but my real question is wether the java akka version is completely equivalent to the scala akka version.